# Prove $S$ is a subset of the irrational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $α$ is an irrational number. Prove that $$S = \left\{
\frac{\alpha}{n} + q \ \middle|\ n \in \mathbb{N},\text{ }q \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$$
is a subset of the irrational numbers.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the rationals are closed under addition and multiplication?

Comment: Have you considered using contradiction?

Comment: Basically, this problem is asking you to prove, if $\alpha$ is irrational, $n\in\mathbb N$ and $q\in\mathbb Q$ then $\frac{\alpha}{n}+q$ is irrational. The set notation is just there to get you comfortable with the set theory conceps, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** $\frac{\alpha}{n}$ is an irrational number. The sum of an irrational and rational number is ...

Comment: a rational number?

Comment: @YenChuanOi but then the difference of a rational and rational number is irrational. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. So is it a contradiction?

Comment: If someone could readily understand an answer of this sort, it seems improbable that they would have phrased the question in the way this was phrased.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: To arrive at a contradiction, suppose that you can find a number $s$ in $S$ such that $s$ is rational. Since $s$ is a member of $S$, we can write $$s = \frac{\alpha}{n} + q$$ for some positive integer $n$ and rational number $q$. What can you say about $ns - nq$?

Comment: ns-nq is a rational number?

Comment: Yes. But $ns - nq$ is also equal to $\alpha$. There's your contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We prove $S \subset \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$.  To do this, we show

$s \in S \Longrightarrow s \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q; \tag 0$

Let

$s \in S; \tag 1$

then

$s = \dfrac{\alpha}{m} + r, \tag 2$

for some $m \in \Bbb N$ and $r \in Q$; if

$s \in \Bbb Q, \tag 3$

then

$\dfrac{\alpha}{m} = s - r. \in \Bbb Q, \tag 4$

whence

$\alpha = m(s - r) \in \Bbb Q; \tag 5$

but this contradicts our hypothesis that $\alpha \notin \Bbb Q$; thus

$s \notin \Bbb Q, \tag 6$

that is

$s \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q, \tag 7$

the irrationals.  Therefore

$S \subset  \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q; \tag 8$

that is, $S$ is a subset of the irrational numbers.

***Note Added in Edit, Sunday 17 September 2017 10:11 AM PST:***  This in response to the comment of Yen Chuan Qi below.  We proved here that every element of $S$ is an element of $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$; this, by definition, implies $S \subset \Bbb R - \Bbb Q$; however, by far the majority of irrationals are not in $S$; this is seen since $S$ is clearly *countable*, whilst $\Bbb R - \Bbb Q$ is not, being all reals but for a countable set.  It is a relatively easy matter to find an irrational number not in $S$.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: I thought that there will be some irrational number which doesn't exist in the subset S since it's a "subset". The conclusion you made prove that S⊂R∖Q means that the factor of S is all irrational number. Or i can just prove S is the set of irrational number?

Comment: @YenChuanOi:  in response to your comment, I made some modifications to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $\dfrac\alpha n + q\vphantom{\frac 1{\displaystyle\int}}$ were rational, then you would have $\dfrac \alpha n + q = \dfrac a b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb N$ and $q = \dfrac c d$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb N,$ so
\begin{align}
& \frac \alpha n + \frac c d = \frac a b \\[10pt]
& \alpha = \frac{nad - ncb}{bd} = \frac{\text{integer}}{\text{integer}},
\end{align}
so $\alpha$ would be rational.